# Prove that there exists $C$ such that $CB = A$ if and only if $\mathcal{N}(B) \subset \mathcal{N}(A)$

Tags: matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times m}$. Show that there exists $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ such that $CB = A$ if and only if $\mathcal{N}(B) \subset \mathcal{N}(A)$. $\mathcal{N}$ indidates the null space.

Comment: what is the $\mathcal{N}?$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $\mathcal{N}$ is the null space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming  $\mathcal{N}$ means $\ker$.

"$\Rightarrow$":$\space$ If such $C$ exists then for $x\in\ker(B)$ we have $Ax=CBx=0$, hence  $x\in\ker(A)$.

"$\Leftarrow$":$\space$ Assume $\ker(B)\subset\ker(A)\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ holds. Let $(b_1,...,b_k)$ be a basis of $\ker(B)$. Extend to a basis $(b_1,...,b_k,a_1,...,a_l)$ of $\ker(A)$. Extend again to a basis $(b_1,...,b_k,a_1,...,a_l,e_1,...,e_r)$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Consider the vectors $(Ba_i)_{1\leq i\leq l}$ and $(Be_i)_{1\leq i\leq r}$. Then the vectors $(Ba_1,...Ba_l,Be_1,...,Be_r)$ are linearly independant (check!).

Now any $C:\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying
$$C(Ba_i)=0,\space\space C(Be_i)=Ae_i$$
will do the job.

Comment: How to prove that there always exists $C$ satisfies $C(Ba_i) = 0$ and $C(Be_i)=Ae_i$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775840/defining-a-linear-transformation-given-a-basis-for-the-domain

Comment: Got it. Thank you.